# Vertical lifts on vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

So let us assume we have a vector bundle $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ and $\nabla$ a connection on $g$.I know that if $v\in E_p$, then there is the standard embedding of $v$ in $T_eE$ where $\pi(e)=p$. Namely we can send $v\mapsto [e+tv]$. While this definition works, it is not practical for computation. So I was wondering if their was an alternative definition for the vertical lifts. In particular it would be great if someone could discuss the construction of the horizontal and vertical lifts. I am still a bit confused about the construction. In addition I am unsure why given a vector field $X\in\Gamma TM$ its horizontal lift $\tilde X\in\Gamma TE$. I've been looking at Peterson's text and it seems he omits some details.

Comment: Can someone give me a good reference to these constructions. A book that talks about horizontal and vertical lifts. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: For the vertical lift I am not aware of an alternative definition (and I don't see why the definition you have given is unpractical for computations). For the horizontal lift, you define $\tilde X$ in a point $e$ to be the unique tangent vector in $T_eE$, which is horizontal and projects onto $X(p(e))$. That these values fit together smoothly is essentially the definition of smoothness of a connection, so you get a vector field on $E$. Concerning a reference, you can try P. Michors "Topics in Differential Geometry" which does this for general fiber bundles.